# How to record an email deferred by ISP for some reason?

Tags: php, sendmail

I want to save record of emails which deferred by ISP for some reason and put them in queue to resend based on time provided by ISP.

I am working in PHP with `mail()` function for this.

Can any one guide me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean email that has been rejected (bounced)?

Comment: No, i mean email has been put in queue list for some reason and send it after x time.

Comment: You would first need to know if and when they do that. Once you have handed off an email via SMTP, you won't know when it has been sent to all recipients - that becomes the problem of the ISP.

Comment: Yes i know that, but we need to know that area of the ISP. Is that not possible to handle in PHP ?

Comment: As I said, "once you have handed off an email via SMTP, you won't know when it has been sent to all recipients". So, it's not possible in any language, unless you manage the SMTP server yourself. (You need to use @halfer to ping me, incidentally).